# Keystore generated on windows machine can be used on unix machine

Tags: java, tomcat, keytool

Hi Stackoverflow guys,

I am a newbie to Java and have a dumb basic question. I have generated a keystore on windows machine and used to enable https in windows tomcat. My question is whether i can use the same keystore on other unix machine to enable https on tomcat installed on unix box?

Comment: Try it out, then you'll see.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me but there is a catch in first name and lastname while creating keystore file, it should be server name where the keystore will be used.

Comment: To be exact, the CommonName (CN) attribute in the cert's Subject field, which `keytool` prompts as '... your first and last name', was traditionally required to be the SSL/TLS server name (normally FQDN) _or_ a wildcard matching the server name(s) (one-level only, see numerous other Qs). For at least a decade now, CN is officially obsolete (though mostly still supported, except Chrome) and the Subject Alternative Name (SAN) _extension_ should be used instead, and it can support multiple names, like `keytool -genkeypair ... -ext san=dns:host1.com,dns:host2.com`